# clicking on multiple images in Listview

Tags: java, android

I got the following App with Costume adapter showing 2 images and 1 textview for each listview.

I can push/click/press each ListView just fine but i want to being able to recognize the X press aswell and i seem to not being able to get the view name or resource name.

[image: ListView with Costume adapter showing two images and one text]
My mainclass with the setOnItemclickListener looks like this

```
serverListView.setOnItemClickListener(new    android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
  //recieve and check if X image is pressed                 
}
});
```

This is the getView method in my Adapter.  I tried to recognize the different image clicks in here without any different results.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position,final  View convertView,final ViewGroup parent)     {
    View row = convertView;
    ServerHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ServerHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.removeIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.removeServer);
        row.setTag(holder);
        }
    else{
        holder = (ServerHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    RowServer rs = servers.get(position);        
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(rs.getIcon());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rs.getName());
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to add listeners to the subitems in `getView(...)`. Try `setOnClickListener(...)` for the views you want to have events attached.

Comment: It works! But i still wan't to be able to catch up the actually item clicked in my MainClass, TextView and such aswell. Oh well. Thanks! :)